# Can't center vertically a div on grid using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How Can I center vertically the card to the other right div content?

[image]

this is my code:

le="margin-bottom:100px">




I Agree With the terms and service   
Request Code

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div style="border-radius:2px;padding:10px;background-color:#2120220e;word-wrap: break-word;text-align:center;width:100%;height:auto" id="description" >Testing</div>

      <div class="line"></div>
    <h3>Your Answer</h3>
    <div style="margin-bottom:100px">
      <div  style="padding:10px"  class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="10" placeholder="Description" class="form-control" id="upload-editor"></textarea >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control control--checkbox">I Agree With the terms and service   <input type="checkbox" id="TOS" name="scales"></label>
        <button style="float:right" onclick="upload()"  class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Request Code</button>
    </div>   
    </div>
  

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could look into flex layout, letting both element stay in the same flex layout, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Answer (score 1):

I would first remove the `margin-bottom: 100px;` and then add the class  `align-self-center` to each `div` I have in the `row`. By doing that you can make sure your `divs` are always centered even if you add padding-top or bottom or margin to the `div` with the class `col-lg`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 align-self-center">
      <div style="border-radius:2px;padding:10px;background-color:#2120220e;word-wrap: break-word;text-align:center;width:100%;height:auto" id="description">Testing</div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <h3>Your Answer</h3>
      <div>
        <div style="padding:10px" class="form-group">
          <textarea rows="10" placeholder="Description" class="form-control" id="upload-editor"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control control--checkbox">I Agree With the terms and service <input
                                type="checkbox" id="TOS" name="scales"></label>
          <button style="float:right" onclick="upload()" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Request
                            Code</button>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 align-self-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If that doesn't help please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container h-100">
<div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div style="border-radius:2px;padding:10px;background-color:#2120220e;word-wrap: break-word;text-align:center;width:100%;height:auto" id="description" >Testing</div>

      <div class="line"></div>
    <h3>Your Answer</h3>
    <div style="margin-bottom:100px">
      <div  style="padding:10px"  class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="10" placeholder="Description" class="form-control" id="upload-editor"></textarea >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control control--checkbox">I Agree With the terms and service   <input type="checkbox" id="TOS" name="scales"></label>
        <button style="float:right" onclick="upload()"  class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Request Code</button>
    </div>   
    </div>
  

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```